# remove all elements that occur more than once from array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Before people think this is the same as all these other answers on Stack Overflow regarding removing duplicates can you please look at what is returned as opposed to what I am looking to do.

I want to remove all elements that occur more than once. I have tried the following:

```js
const a = ['Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Maradona', 'Messi', 'Pele'];

const uniqueArray = a.filter(function(item, pos) {
  return a.indexOf(item) == pos;
})

console.log(uniqueArray)
```

I want my `uniqueArray` to be

```
['Ronaldo', 'Maradona', 'Messi'];
```

Comment: that contains `Pele`. Look closely

Comment: Ah okay, so you want to remove all elements that occur more than once ...

Comment: yep, @JonasWilms updated the question as it probably wasn't very clear

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short: keep the value if the position of the first occurrence of the element (`indexOf`) is also the last position of the element in the array (`lastIndexOf`).

If the indexes are not equal then the value is duplicated and you can discard it.

```js
const a = ['Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Maradona', 'Messi', 
           'Pele', 'Messi', 'Van Basten', 'Baggio', 
           'Messi', 'Seedorf', 'Maradona'];
    
const uniqueArray = a.filter(function(item) {
  return a.lastIndexOf(item) == a.indexOf(item);
});

console.log(uniqueArray);
/* output:  ["Ronaldo", "Van Basten", "Baggio", "Seedorf"] */
```

Another idea is to perform an array iteration, add the values as the keys of an object, count the occurrences and then keep the keys with a total of occurrences equal to 1.

```js
const a = ['Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Maradona', 'Messi', 
           'Pele', 'Messi', 'Van Basten', 'Baggio', 
           'Messi', 'Seedorf', 'Maradona'];
    
const obj = {};
const uniqueArray = [];

a.forEach((item) => {
  obj[item] = (typeof obj[item] === 'undefined')? 1 : ++obj[item];
});

for (let key in obj) {
  if (obj[key] === 1) {
    uniqueArray.push(key)
  }
}

console.log(uniqueArray);
/* output:  ["Ronaldo", "Van Basten", "Baggio", "Seedorf"] */
```

The complexity of this code is linear while the first solution is quadratic.

I made [a benchmark on JSPerf](https://jsperf.app/dowubu/6) and the last approach is `~11x` times faster using an array of `535` items with `119` unique values.

Comment: I will have to give you an up vote just for adding Baggio :-D

Comment: And consider that Baggio did all what he has done with one leg only, for a great part of his career.

Comment: Note that for long arrays this is very inefficient (quadratic number of comparisons) although for ES<6 and mixed types it's hard to do better.

Comment: @user202729 found a better approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can count the item in each iteration so that you can include that in the condition:

```js
const a = ['Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Maradona', 'Messi', 'Pele'];

const uniqueArray = a.filter(function(item, pos) {
  var c = a.filter(i => i==item).length;
  return a.indexOf(item) == pos && c <= 1;
})

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Though the better solution would be to compare the index of the current array item with [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf):

```js
const a = ['Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Maradona', 'Messi', 'Pele'];

const uniqueArray = a.filter(function(item, pos) {
  return a.indexOf(item) === a.lastIndexOf(item);
})

console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilise a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to count how many times each entry shows up and then only take the ones that only do so once.

```js
const a = ['Ronaldo', 'Pele', 'Maradona', 'Messi', 'Pele'];

const uniqueArray = onlyUniqueItems(a);

console.log(uniqueArray)


function onlyUniqueItems(array) {
  const map = new Map();
  const result = [];
  
  array.forEach(item => {
    let amount = map.get(item) || 0;
    map.set(item, ++amount); //pre-increment and then set the amount
  });
  
  map.forEach((amount, item) => {
    if (amount == 1) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}
```

This will run in O(2n) as you will have to do two scans at most. You can achieve a similar result using a plain object and set key-values on it but a Map has the advantage of preserving the type of the items you had, whereas a plain object will convert all keys to strings:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 3, "4", "4", "5"];

const uniqueArray = onlyUniqueItems(a);
const uniqueArrayUsingObject = onlyUniqueItemsUsingObject(a);

console.log(uniqueArray)
console.log(uniqueArrayUsingObject)


function onlyUniqueItems(array) {
  const map = new Map();
  const result = [];
  
  //count occurences
  array.forEach(item => {
    let amount = map.get(item) || 0;
    map.set(item, ++amount); //pre-increment and then set the amount
  });
  
  //extract only the items that show once
  map.forEach((amount, item) => {
    if (amount == 1) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}


function onlyUniqueItemsUsingObject(array) {
  const map = {};
  const result = [];
  
  //count occurences
  array.forEach(item => {
    let amount = map[item] || 0;
    map[item] = ++amount; //pre-increment and then set the amount
  });
  
  //extract only the items that show once
  Object.entries(map).forEach(([item, amount]) => {
    if (amount == 1) {
      result.push(item);
    }
  });
  
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The naive way would be to check for more than one occurence:

```
   a.filter((el, i) => !(a.indexOf(el) !== i || a.indexOf(el, i) > -1)));
```

Or a more complicated one with multiple Sets (but O(n)):

```
  const found = new Set, values = new Set;

  for(const el of a)
   if(!found.has(el)) {
     found.add(el);
     values.add(el);
   } else if(values.has(el) {
     values.delete(el);
   }
 }

 const result = [...values.values()];
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not to use `Set`?

```
const theSet = new Set(a);
const values = set.values();
const uniqueArray = Array.from(values);
```

Comment: Because OP wants to ignore duplicate values *entirely* - if a value has a duplicate, don't include it at all.