# Drop all duplicates from array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, duplicates

I have an array of objects with input like below

```
var jsonArray1 = [{id:'1',name:'John'},{id:'2',name:'Smith'},{id:'3',name:'Adam'},{id:'1',name:'John'}]
```

The id 1 appears twice and I would like to drop all duplicate records .i.e. my output should look like

```
[{id:'2',name:'Smith'},{id:'3',name:'Adam'}]
```

Can you please guide/direct me in how I can drop all duplicate records

Comment: There's no such thing as a JSON array. `jsonArray1` is an array of objects, nothing more.

Comment: This is a similar question: [remove all elements that occur more than once from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53066843) You need to implement the same for objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `Map` from an array where key of the `Map` is your desired `id`, duplicated won't be preserved (only last occurrence will). After just take the values from `Map`.

Removing all of occurrences of duplicates (this is what OP wanted):

```js
const input = [{id:'1',name:'John'},
               {id:'2',name:'Smith'},
               {id:'3',name:'Adam'},
               {id:'1',name:'John'}]

const res = input.filter((x, i, arr) => 
                          arr.filter(e => e.id === x.id).length === 1)
console.log(res)
```

Preserving 1 occurrence of duplicates:

```js
const input = [{id:'1',name:'John'},
               {id:'2',name:'Smith'},
               {id:'3',name:'Adam'},
               {id:'1',name:'John'}]

const unique = [...new Map(input.map(item => [item.id, item])).values()]
console.log(unique)
```

Comment: it drops just the duplicate record. my requirement is to drop all such occurrences where a duplicate is found. the output should be just
 [ {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Adam"
  }
]

Comment: My bad, updated, check it now.